# How to display received/sent bytes over Bluetooth on Mac

Tags: macos, bluetooth

**How can I see the raw data stream sent/received from my Mac to/from a Bluetooth LE device?**

I tried /var/log/Bluetooth from within console. But I don't see any data there.

Background: I have a small application to receive data from external sensor. My implementation on Mac using CBCentralManager is working as expected. An similar application using Bluetopia stack on Linux is not working. So I want to compare which data are missing.

Answer (score 1):

The best tools I found are from Apple: Bluetooth Explorer.app and PacketLogger.app are part of the **Additional Tools for Xcode**.

Comment: Using Bluetooth explorer, how can we see the received data?